# Axios Network Error in Android when calling local API

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I am very new with react native and building an app which calls a backend api in .NET core.

Here is my API calling part written

```
export const addNewMember = async (newMember: Member) => {
Alert.alert('10');
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'http://localhost:5004/Members',
      newMember,
      {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
    Alert.alert('2');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert('3');
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

But whenever it executes, I am getting a timeout, nothing else.

I changed to 10.0.2.2:5004 based on someone suggested, But it still the same timeout.

I checked my API using POSTMAN which is working without any issue.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your local ip address ?

```html
export const addNewMember = async (newMember: Member) => {

//replace 192.168.10.1 with your local ip . to get your ip address run ifconfig in terminal
Alert.alert('10');
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'http://192.168.10.1:5004/Members',
      newMember,
      {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
    Alert.alert('2');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert('3');
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```